# How does youtube-dl generate direct link?

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm wondering how youtube-dl generate direct link to video. I know that 
with *youtube-dl --get-url link* I can get this, but I want to know how this process goes. (From downloading html page to getting link). Is there a way to check this out? 
Youtube-dl is open-source so I guess it is, but I just don't know where specifically I should look. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

youtube-dl uses classes called `InfoExtractor` to make it possible to download videos from different sites. The info extractor for youtube videos is in [`/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/2015.07.18/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L874).

This class is quite complex, since it deals with logging in users and different kinds of videos and channels etc. I think that the relevant part is:

```
url = proto + '://www.youtube.com/watch?v=%s&gl=US&hl=en&has_verified=1&bpctr=9999999999' % video_id
```

Where the `video_id` is extracted by a [big regex](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/2015.07.18/youtube_dl/extractor/youtube.py#L197):

```
_VALID_URL = r"""(?x)^
                 (
                     (?:https?://|//)                                    # http(s):// or protocol-independent URL
                     (?:(?:(?:(?:\w+\.)?[yY][oO][uU][tT][uU][bB][eE](?:-nocookie)?\.com/|
                        (?:www\.)?deturl\.com/www\.youtube\.com/|
                        (?:www\.)?pwnyoutube\.com/|
                        (?:www\.)?yourepeat\.com/|
                        tube\.majestyc\.net/|
                        youtube\.googleapis\.com/)                        # the various hostnames, with wildcard subdomains
                     (?:.*?\#/)?                                          # handle anchor (#/) redirect urls
                     (?:                                                  # the various things that can precede the ID:
                         (?:(?:v|embed|e)/(?!videoseries))                # v/ or embed/ or e/
                         |(?:                                             # or the v= param in all its forms
                             (?:(?:watch|movie)(?:_popup)?(?:\.php)?/?)?  # preceding watch(_popup|.php) or nothing (like /?v=xxxx)
                             (?:\?|\#!?)                                  # the params delimiter ? or # or #!
                             (?:.*?&)?                                    # any other preceding param (like /?s=tuff&v=xxxx)
                             v=
                         )
                     ))
                     |youtu\.be/                                          # just youtu.be/xxxx
                     |(?:www\.)?cleanvideosearch\.com/media/action/yt/watch\?videoId=
                     )
                 )?                                                       # all until now is optional -> you can pass the naked ID
                 ([0-9A-Za-z_-]{11})                                      # here is it! the YouTube video ID
                 (?!.*?&list=)                                            # combined list/video URLs are handled by the playlist IE
                 (?(1).+)?                                                # if we found the ID, everything can follow
                 $"""
```

Luckily it's commented...

Comment: all this regex does is find the youtube id from the url supplied by the user.  the page for that id has to be parsed to dig out the direct media url's for different formats (stored in a javascript variable), and must include a signature that has to be decrypted.  the result of `youtube-dl -g <youtube url>` looks like `https://r2---sn-nx5e6n76.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?key=yt6&mime=video%2Fmp4&...`  it includes a parameter like `signature=CFC671E06803D382B6F7A403AFE1CB4AFFD3742F.01BF1F977DCF2018BE0318E4A0B6670C750A67D4` that `youtube.py` has to decrypt from the `s` javascript variable.

Comment: see `_extract_signature_function` in `youtube.py`

Comment: The answer is not correct. @user1441998 seems to get it right.

Comment: @Leo Totally - the comment would have been better as an edit or a separate answer :) What do you think, should I update my own answer with the comment?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo - well an answer would get into how the decryption works...

Comment: @AndréLaszlo Yes, please update the answer and mention that it was a misunderstanding. (The real answer is simply to read the source code for youtube-dl...)